# Teradata: How to change timestamp from one time zone to another

Tags: timestamp, timezone, teradata

We are receiving a field from a vendor that represents the timestamp of when a particular transaction took place. We are told the value passed to us is in GMT. I want to take that value and convert it to EST. I know I could just subtract 5 hours from it, but would like to use something more dynamic that would considered daylight savings.

The **timestamp** value we receive looks like this:

```
 20220609 22:13:39.000
```

I can convert it to a timestamp using the following:

```
CAST ("**timestamp**" AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDBHH:MI:SSDS(F)')
```

Just don't know how to convert that final value to EST.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have time zone support enabled, recommended option would be to store as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and specify to the database that the value is GMT. You can do that explicitly

```
CAST ("timestamp"||'+00:00' AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDBHH:MI:SSDS(F)Z')
```

Or if the session time zone when loading the data is GMT (which could be specified as user-level default or via explicit `SET TIME ZONE 'GMT';`) then the time zone could be implied.

```
CAST ("timestamp" AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDBHH:MI:SSDS(F)')
```

For queries, if you then CAST to `TIMESTAMP` (without TIME ZONE) the database will by default convert to session time zone or you can use [AT time zone specifier](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Date-and-Time-Functions-and-Expressions/July-2021/DateTime-and-Interval-Functions-and-Expressions/ANSI-DateTime-Expressions) syntax to explicitly convert to `'America Central'` and then CAST to `TIMESTAMP` or a display string that does not include the time zone.

If you insist on storing as `TIMESTAMP` data type: First convert the string to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` as above. Then convert the value `AT 'America Central'` to a formatted string (using `TO_CHAR` or `CAST`), omitting the time zone suffix. And finally, convert that string back to `TIMESTAMP` (using `CAST` or `TO_TIMESTAMP`)